# Is it possible to change Ghostery to block anything automatically? 

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is it possible to change the Ghostery extension to block anything automatically?

Every time you surf a new website you have to check what trackers are following you and block them manually. I would like to have them blocked automatically – no matter what sort of tracker it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What? Ghostery asks you, right after the install, what you want to block. If you want to block at all.

By answering yes (ticking the right boxes), **it'll block them all and also, auto-update it's library all the time**.

Comment: Yes. I found it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your try [Do not Track Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/donottrackplus/?src=ss) instead. It's fully automatic.

> Do Not Track Plus blocks web beacons and other tracking technologies that advertisers use to track your browsing behavior. Easily see what trackers are in use at each website you visit and block any or all of them.

Comment: I have this installed too but on certain pages I have a list of ad-, spy- or malware which is not blocked by "Do not Track Plus" but "Ghostery".

Comment: Why would you even use them both? It's like installing 25 adblocks just to block ads.

Comment: Because I am not sure if each of them are blocking everything or do both extensions have the same blocking list?

Comment: On this page for example: eight trackers are blocked by ghostery and none by dntp: http://betanews.com/2011/08/13/why-isn-t-apple-protecting-itunes-app-store-users-from-purchase-fraud/